# How can i call a content provider myself in the code?

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest, android-contentprovider, facebook-android-sdk

I want to remove this from my `androidmanifest` file :

```
<provider android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider"
                android:authorities="%package%.FacebookInitProvider"
                android:exported="false" />
```

because it's make Facebook network request every time my app is launch, even if the user will never use any Facebook api. Instead, I want to call myself `com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider` when I will need to use a Facebook API. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you considered just disabling/enabling that component as needed? You can do that with the `PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. the problem is that if I use setComponentEnabledSetting then I will need to leave in the manifest the provider android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" .. and in this way before I disable the component facebook will have already done network request :(

Comment: Add `android:enabled="false"` to the `<provider>` element.

Comment: @MikeM. hmmm this sound good !

Comment: @MikeM. unfortunatly it's seam to not work :( when I do PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting() then it's look like the com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider is not called and thus the facebook package is not initialized :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Facebook SDK. Is there some sort of initialization done in an `Application` subclass? If so, it might take a complete process restart for that to work (which is probably not at all what you want).